# Get python file content from github api and parse to dict

Tags: python, git, python-requests

I'm integrating with github api to list our projects into local database.

The projects  are basically repos with branches that contains python packages each package has a manifest file which include only 1 dict that holds the package details .. package name,version,etc..

I already listed the repo& branchs but i need to have the ability to read these manifest files content as dict

When i try to access the manifest files i got [base64 content](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#response-if-content-is-a-file) which i can't encode to python code.

How could i decode these files into .py files or extract the dict from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried an other approach to get the file content as from Github api response,it send the download url which is the file + access token,so i used that url to do `requests.get()` then i used `ast` lib to convert the text to python dict